# How to show a virtual keyboard for InputDialog?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, virtual-keyboard

In my swing application on clicking a button, an InputDialog box gets poped up to get the user's input which is number only. This application will run on touch panels.

Does Swing provide a prebuilt virtual keyboard which I can use when the cursor is on InputDialog Textfield or do I have to create a custom keyboard explicitly?

Comment: most touch panels have system keyboards for things like that. Don't you have access to touch panels that you are describing?

Comment: @Szprota21 this application for POS machines used in retail stores. Vitual Keyboard that you are talking about belong to different application which handles transaction. This one is a utility application for which I can't used Virtual Keyboard which is used for transaction. There's no other keyboard accessible from machine.

Comment: then you will need to make your own keyboard. Or check this or other premade dependencies https://github.com/comtel2000/fx-experience

Comment: @Szprota21 said what I was going to say: That it's almost certain that you can get a visual keyboard on GitHub